# Can I get the maximal key of every RDD in DStream?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I need to find the largest key of every RDD, but when use reduce(), what I can get is the largest one in the whole Dstream.
For example,in this stream, what I want to get back is (2,"b"),(2,"d"),(3,"f"), but I can only get (3,"f") by `reduce(max)`
How can I get (2,"b"),(2,"d"),(3,"f")?

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingQueueStream")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
stream = ssc.queueStream([sc.parallelize([(1,"a"), (2,"b"),(1,"c"),(2,"d"),
(1,"e"),(3,"f")],3)])

stream.reduce(max).pprint()
ssc.start()
ssc.stop(stopSparkContext=True, stopGraceFully=True)
```

Comment: There is only one `RDD` in the stream....

Comment: I am sorry, but I divided data into 3 parts by 'sc.parallelize'

Comment: No... Please read what `minPartitions` is doing :) Pass 3 RDDs you get `max` for each batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
stream = ssc.queueStream([sc.parallelize([(1,"a"), (2,"b"),(1,"c"),(2,"d"),
  (1,"e"),(3,"f")],3)])
```

creates a stream with only one batch where the first and only batch has (minimum) 3 partitions. I guess you want:

```
stream = ssc.queueStream([
    sc.parallelize([(1,"a"), (2,"b")]),
    sc.parallelize([(1,"c"), (2,"d")]), 
    sc.parallelize([(1,"e"), (3,"f")]), 
])
```

Which will give you expected result with:

```
stream.reduce(max).pprint()
```

Comment: Thank you very much and I have the other question. In my code , I divided the data into 3 partitions, if I use ' 1 ' instead of ' 3 ', the result will be the same. So what is the meaning of transformation 'parallelize'? Saving our processing time or something else?

Comment: Result of `reduce` with `max` won't depend on number of partitions. `parallelize` creates RDD. `minPartitions` set number of partitions for this RDD.

Comment: Sorry I still feel confused about the meaning of partitions. Can more partitions save more operating time? or just divide big data into small one to help  assign for more computers?

Comment: DStream is a infinite stream of RDDs where each RDD (batch) has one or more partitions. Partitions are about data distribution.  Stream is not.